# Function to find first available option based on count of records and condition

Tags: mysql

I need to write an SQL statement to get the first 'free' poule (pool / collection of teams) for my team. Let's explain a bit.
I have two tables, one table poules with 4 poules each having a TEAMQTY of 4 (the max. number of teams allowed in a poule):

```
ID  TOURNID     NAME       TEAMQTY
1        1      Poule 1         4
2        1      Poule 2         4
3        1      Poule 3         4
4        1      Poule 4         4
```

and a table teams

```
ID  TOURNID     NAME    POULEID
1   1           Team 1        1
2   1           Team 2        1
3   1           Team 3        1
4   1           Team 4        1
```

I want to write a function in mysql which based on the situation above suggest a pouleid of 2 since poule 1 is completely filled up with teams. IOW I should be able to insert 4 more teams in PouleId 2, after that my function should return PouleID 3 as a suggestion.

I'm new to mysql (an sql noob) and I've tried:

```
SELECT id FROM POULES WHERE TOURNID = 1 AND 
teamqty > (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TEAMS WHERE TOURNID = 1) LIMIT 1
```

Needless to say my experiment sql code is useless..
Do I need a while loop here or would an SQL statement do?

Here's my supporting code:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `poules` (
  `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `TOURNID` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `NAME` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `TEAMQTY` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 KEY `TOURNID` (`TOURNID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=5 ;


INSERT INTO `poules` (`ID`, `TOURNID`, `NAME`, `TEAMQTY`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1',  4),
(2, 1, '2',  4),
(3, 1, '3',  4),
(4, 1, '4',  4);


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `teams` (
 `ID` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `TOURNID` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
 `POULEID` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`ID`),
 UNIQUE KEY `NAME` (`NAME`),
 KEY `TOURNID` (`TOURNID`))
ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=6 ;



INSERT INTO `teams` (`ID`, `TOURNID`, `NAME`, `POULEID`) VALUES
(1, 1, '1', 1),
(2, 1, '2', 1),
(3, 1, '3', 1),
(4, 1, '4', 1);
```

TIA Mike

Comment: This isn't helpful for your actual question, but I'm almost certain you mean 'pool', if you're referring to a collection of teams in a tournament.

Comment: Correct Gian! I'll update my question thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do `left join` with a subquery that gets `total team count` and compares with team count in the main table

you can use limit to get the one result based on order by on team count.

```
select p.id as pouleid, ifnull(t.teamcount,0), p.tournid
from poules p
left join ( select count(pouleid) as teamcount, pouleid, tournid
            from teams
            group by pouleid, tournid
)t
on p.id = t.pouleid
and p.tournid = t.tournid
where ifnull(t.teamcount,0) < p.teamqty
```